# QGIS Adding categorial color to points from CSV

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS and couldn't find any answers to this question I had.

I'm importing data from a CSV file into QGIS using Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer. Here are a few lines of sample data:

> 1,0,-72.27141,42.564782,ATHOL,15 1,1,-72.27141,42.573775,ATHOL,15
>   1,7,-72.25924,42.573775,ATHOL,15 1,8,-72.25924,42.582768,ATHOL,15
>   1,12,-72.24707,42.564782,ATHOL,15 1,14,-72.24707,42.582768,ATHOL,15
>   1,18,-72.2349,42.555789,ATHOL,15 2,21,-72.2349,42.582768,ATHOL,15
>   2,23,-72.2349,42.600754,ATHOL,15 2,24,-72.2349,42.609747,ATHOL,15
>   2,34,-72.22273,42.582768,ATHOL,15 2,35,-72.22273,42.591761,ATHOL,15
>   2,36,-72.22273,42.600754,ATHOL,15 2,37,-72.22273,42.609747,ATHOL,15

I am graphing column 3 as the X-coordinate and column 4 as the Y-coordinate.

However, I would really like to color-code these by column 1 so it is easier to see the groupings on my map. For instance, any coordinate where column 1 = 1 can display a random color (ex. green) and coordinates where column 1 = 2 can display another random color (ex. red).

I kind of found a way to do this, but it is extremely tedious as I have a couple thousand data points and a hundred or so items in column 1.

What I have been doing is going to Properties > Style > changing from Single Symbol to Categorized > setting column to 1 > setting a random color ramp > then add categories and setting their value manually from 1, 2, etc.

Is there an automated way to do this, so I don't have to set hundreds of categories and enter values manually?

Comment: You may select the field for which you want to apply the categorized style (for your case, the first field): you select it just below the selector where you choose the categorized style. Once you have done this, you need to set a color ramp and the push the "Classify" button; then, you only need to push the apply button.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I'll copy my text as answer, so it will be useful for other users ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may select the field for which you want to apply the categorized style (for your case, the first field): you select it just below the selector where you choose the categorized style. Once you have done this, you need to set a color ramp and the push the "Classify" button; then, you only need to push the apply button.